# Python: Convert Networks bits to Binary

Tags: python, networking, binary, converters, subnet

So i want to Convert network bits(CIDR) to Binary

i tried to search on google but it give me nothing only give me ipcalculator and stuff

but i read some article that show me how to convert decimal to binary

the problem is i need to figure out how to change network bits to decimal

```
for example i use 28(/28) the netmask should be 255.255.255.240 i just want to use the 240
so that i can convert it to binary it should give me 11110000
```

i tried to lookup on google how to do it but only giving me how to convert binary to decimal

Can you anyone give me a link or teach me how to do it

or there's alternative way like i dont have to convert network bits to decimal

I try to keep on update about my progress

Comment: i try to use list,array,and dict method right now so i dont have to convert network bit to decimal

Comment: An IPv4 mask, like an IPv4 address, is really a 32-bit unsigned integer, and the dotted decimal notation is simply to make it easier for humans to read. The octets are meaningless. You can set the mask to `0xffffffff` and shift it left `(32 - length)` times, then convert it to a binary string, and for  a mask length of `28` you get `0b11111111111111111111111111110000`. At that point, you can take whatever part of the string you want, for example, the last eight characters would be the last octet of the mask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mask = "255.255.255.240"
#Last_char takes the last 3 digits of ur mask
last_char = int(mask[-3])
#Then it converts it to binary
dec_to_bin = bin(last_char)
#There is the result
print (dec_to_bin)
```

The output should be: `0b10`

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful @Zaxmittas